# I can't found what is wrong with urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I can't find where is bug. It's my begining with django. If somebody helping me i will grateful.

urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns, include
from django.contrib import admin
from superlista.lists import views

urlpatterns = [
#    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.home_page, name='home'),
]
```

views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render


# Create your views here.
def home_page():
    pass
```

[image: directory view]

`python manage.py runserver`

```
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x03917468>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vnbox\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vnbox\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\vnbox\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\vnbox\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\vnbox\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 10, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\vnbox\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 19, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\vnbox\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\vnbox\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\vnbox\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\vnbox\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\vnbox\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\vnbox\PycharmProjects\kurs_h\superlista\superlista\urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    from superlista.lists import views
ImportError: No module named 'superlista.lists'
```

I can't find where is bug. It's my begining with django. If somebody helping me i will grateful.

Comment: superlista.list may be a wrong path

Comment: Do you add `lists` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py`?

Comment: @LostMyGlasses: Yes, I added

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your screenshot of your folder structure, the outer superlista is the project root, and the installed apps are `superlista` and `lists`.

If you have correctly defined the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting, your import should be:

```
from lists import views
```